# Avoid Burning bridges with a long time employer who I just rejoined

Tags: software-industry, resignation, burning-bridges

I worked for company A for  4 years and quit due to no technical growth and moved to B, It was good and worked there for  10 months. It is in Asia. Then my old boss called few times to join saying I can join on my terms. First time I rejected, second time I accepted. Since I got a promotion and manager said I can join on my terms. But after joining, It is the same place and no technical growth for me.

Now I got another offer where I got 20 percent more with more technical growth. It is a ideal job for me in a different industry. I checked the company is good through a contact. How can I exit nicely now and I am still under probation. But they badly need me because It is not a job everyone wants ( high pressure and bugs fixing). To put the ball on their court, I asked to relocate to a remote development team. No final outcome on that.

My main concerns to move out are

1. Burning bridges, I have some good rapport with colleagues, managers and supervisors. Any way to avoid this even If I go?
2. Any negative references possible in future?
3. Will I be considered as a job hopper? Actually, I tried my best to stay here that's why I came back but it is not possible I realized due to the organization structure.

EDIT:
Thanks for all the comments. I am thinking to not burn any bridges and leave my employer. But I plan to be candid about my situation and give them 3 to 4 months to work on it e.g moving to a different development team. I will take it. I also propose to train another person to do the job. Anyway, since the software job market is good, I am confident that I can find a job later..

Comment: When the old boss said that you could rejoin "on your terms", what terms did you give them?

Comment: more development scope.

Comment: Maybe I'm being a bit callous, but my coercing you to rejoin this job that nobody wants and then reneging on their promises, it sounds like if any bridges get burned, they're the ones doing the burning? My attitude does ignore the human factor and the relationships you've made, but it sounds like they should understand.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Burning bridges, I have some good rapport with colleagues, managers
> and supervisors. Any way to avoid this even If I go?

Probably not. Leaving, rejoining, then leaving again within a short time after getting a promotion likely burns some bridges - probably with both Company A and Company B.

> Any negative references possible in future?

Negative references are always possible. Hopefully, other than the leaving part, you have been a stellar worker to minimize that possibility.

> Will I be considered as a job hopper?

If this is the only case, then you probably won't be considered a job hopper.

You may be considered high maintenance, indecisive and/or not really knowing what you want in your career. But there's not really much you can do about it, other than being ready to explain in an interview why you made the moves and why you won't leave your new company after a short period of time if you are hired.

Comment: Thanks Joe. See my edit. I planned to stay. Basically postponing it giving my employer some time. You think it is okay?

Answer (score 9):

***I am still under probation.***

The probation period works both ways: to see if you are a good fit for the job and to see if your job is a good fit for you. That's why it's a probation.

You shouldn't feel bad for quitting during a probation, because that's exactly what it's meant for.

Your employer is also under probation.

Comment: Legally it's definitely fine, but in terms of burning bridges & what it might look like to a potential employer — it may come across as strange, given that they already knew the company culture before going in.

Comment: @anotherdave And the company already knew the employee, yet they wanted the probation.

Comment: @pipe true! Fair point.

Answer (score 2):

I can understand this, having returned to a previous employer, but you need to take this experience on board for future roles. Returning can often feel like the 'safety blanket' but you should also think about the reasons you left in the first place and not immediately jump at the opportunity to go back if it ever arises.

How are you defining growth? Is this financial or personal/career development?
What goals have you set yourself within work? Does the work with the organisation align to where you want to develop?

These kind of questions really are applicable to any job role that you have, not just to return to a previous employer. Unless you were mis-informed when you went back to your old job, it seems like you are not questioning yourself enough on motives and career direction as well as questioning future employers to see if both are aligned in order that you are successfully challenged in any job you do